# Probabilistic resource selection considering load/weight

Tags: c++, boost, random

Say I have a map like:

[image]

Now, I need to pick a resource randomly using [weighted random selection](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/). But, the resource with highest load should have the lowest probability of selection [for example, R2 should have lowest probability]. So, what I'm doing now for calculating probabilities is:

```
At first taking sum of values of the map say, totalWeight:

    totalWeight = 1+3+1+1 = 6 (for above example)

    newTotalWeight = (totalWeight - load of R1) + .... + (totalWeight - load of R4)    
                                   = totalWeight * (noOfElements-1)
                                   = 6 * (4-1) = 18
    Finally,
    p(selecting a resource R) = (totalWeight - current load of R) / newTotalWeight 

        So, for above example:
        p(selecting R1) = (6 - 1) / 18 = 5/18
        p(selecting R2) = (6 - 3) / 18 = 3/18
        p(selecting R3) = (6 - 1) / 18 = 5/18
        p(selecting R4) = (6 - 1) / 18 = 5/18

        p(R1, R2, R3, R4) = (5/18, 3/18, 5/18, 5/18)
```

This is exactly what I want. Now, discrete **inverse-transform** method:

```
Generate U~U(0,1)
if U <= p(R1) selectedResource = R1; 
if p(R1) < U <= (p(R1) + p(R2)) selectedResource = R2; 
.......
```

can be used to select a resource.

But I'm using BOOST's discrete_distribution for [generating integers with different probabilities](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_with_different_probabilities).

Now, whenever the load of a resource changes I recalculate probability of each resource using above equation and repeat the whole process.

Am I doing it right or is there any other efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
boost::mt19937 mt(42);
boost::random::discrete_distribution<int, Weight> dist({1,3,1,1});
auto genR = [&] { return static_cast<Resource>(dist(mt)); };

for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
    std::cout << genR() << "\n";
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5dd0d25c2583c90)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random/discrete_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/piecewise_linear_distribution.hpp>

enum Resource { R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 };
using Weight = int;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Resource r) {
    return os << "R" << std::to_string(1+r);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    boost::mt19937 mt(42);
    boost::random::discrete_distribution<int, Weight> dist({1,3,1,1});  
    auto genR = [&] { return static_cast<Resource>(dist(mt)); };

    for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
        std::cout << genR() << "\n";
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
R2
R4
R1
R1
R1
R4
R3
R1
R1
R2
```